# G-WAN v.7.12.6 content type handlers not work

Tags: g-wan

I made a html.c script as below, in .../csp folder. It should output the additional headers with the default headers. But, actually it output the default headers only.
What have I done wrong? Did I miss anything?

Or, is it a bug in G-WAN?

```
#include "gwan.h" // G-WAN exported functions

#define CACHE "Expires: Fri, May 02 2042 00:00:00 GMT\r\nCache-Control: max-age=99999999\r\n"  

int main(int argc, char *argv[ ])
{
    char  cache[ ] = CACHE;
    http_header(HEAD_ADD, cache, sizeof(CACHE) - 1, argv);
    return 200;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't check the code now but my guess is that `http_header()` has never been used from a `content-type handler` (only from `servlets`, like done in G-WAN examples).

It may simply be that the structures allocated by `http_header()` are never used. While `http_header()` is conveniently doing the work for you, G-WAN `handler` examples show how to build or access the reply buffer so you can do whatever header edition you need from this point.